# How to make table visibility as true and false in controller action method in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

based on some condition, i need to make visibility of table such as table1 ,table2, table3. If the condition is not satisfied, then need to make some table visibility as false.

It can be easily achieved in ASP.NET web forms. But i got struck while trying the same with MVC. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a view model with properties such as `bool IsTable1Visible` or assign the value to a `ViewBag` property and then check the value in the view.

Comment: can use data-* attributes. Add data-IsTableVisible for each Table  and then using these values on page load set Visibility